# flowMeans function in R - Error in colMeans(Lj) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to implement flowmeans function available in bioconductor (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/flowMeans.html) in R language over the Levine_13dim_notransform.fcs dataset (after removing the NAN rows) available in row form here https://github.com/lmweber/benchmark-data-Levine-13-dim/tree/master/data.

I tried the following.

```
Y = read.FCS("file_path.fcs",truncate_max_range = FALSE)
res_exprs <- flowMeans((Y), NumC=24, Standardize=FALSE, MaxN = 5)
```

Error:

> Error in solve.default(cov, ...) :    system is computationally
> singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.7647e-24 In addition:
> Warning messages: 1: Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum (=
> 4087350)  2: Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum (= 4087350)

AND

```
res_exprs <- flowMeans((Y), NumC=24, Standardize=FALSE)
```

> Error in colMeans(Lj) : 'x' must be an array of at least two
> dimensions

And some similar combinations. But none seemed to work.
Any suggestions?